# Чем можно бэкапить S3 хранилище?

Tags: linux, администрирование, резервное-копирование, s3

Мы с коллегой начитались про то какой [S3](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3) <s>стильный, модный, молодёжный</s> удобный, отказоустойчивый, вместительный и решили попробовать перенести туда некоторые тяжёлые папки. В тестовом окружении ([minio](https://min.io/)) вроде бы работает, но возник вопрос "а как бэкапить"? Из того, что есть сейчас и неплохо решает задачу - `borg` и `acronis` (лицензия, ага), но у них файловый\блочный уровни, а тут - не совсем.

Answer (score 1):

В [issues](https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/4135) официального репо контрибьютор перечислил инструменты для бекапа:

- Restic https://docs.minio.io/docs/restic-with-minio
- Rclone https://docs.minio.io/docs/rclone-with-minio-server
- Cloudberry Backup https://www.msp360.com/backup.aspx

Также можно сделать [средствами mc](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-client-complete-guide#mirror):

```
mc mirror --remove --preserve $MINIO_ENV/<bucket> $BACKUPS_DIR/$BACKUP_NAME
```

- `$MINIO_ENV` - minio хост (например `myminio`)
- `$BACKUPS_DIR/$BACKUP_NAME` - абсолютный путь к локальному каталогу

`mc` входит в состав minio, и предварительно нужно настроить ее конфиг.

Comment: Ну т.е. надо костылить скрипт+крон вытаскивающий файло, докинуть места, куда сливать уже этот "сырой" вид, который потом уже бэкапить. Я всё правильно понял?

Comment: Почему костылить? Бекап - это одна задача, и делается этими командами. Расписание - это другая задача, если нужно делать периодически - создавайте крон задачу или джобу в гитлабе/кубере/что там у вас. Было бы неправильно делать в минио свой планировщик, поэтому эта проблема решается написанием отдельного скрипта, и это не костыль, а верное решение.